# regex to replace input tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have input Tags like this:

```
<input style="font-size:12px;width:100%" type="text" value="http://www.google.de/ggg">
```

And want to replace them with nothing.
This is, what I tried:

```
$pattern    = '/<input style="font-size:12px;width:100%" type="text" value="(.+?)">/';
        echo preg_replace( $pattern, "", $content )
```

I did not succeed with that.

What is the error in my function? Maybe the regex?

A function which replace all input tags inside the string would be fine.

Comment: it might be good idea to make regexp more general, ie. removing all input text from `$content`, or what would you like to do with `$content`?

Comment: Do you try to parse/change html page? This regex seems fine, tested on $content variable inside php script...

Comment: @mpapec Please have a look at my edit. Replacing all input tags inside the string would be fine.

Comment: @nevermind ...not rellay, I have aphp string form the database, which i want to prepare for an ouutput....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will replace all `input` tags whether they begin with white spaces. `/i` ignores case and `/x` ignores spaces in regexp so it primary purpose is more readable regexp,

```
    echo preg_replace("/<\s* input [^>]+ >/xi", "", $content);
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need some [pattern modifiers](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) I am assuming you have a block of text so try adding `sU` after your pattern.

Comment: be careful with the /U modifier, because if all greedy quantifiers becomes lazy, lazy quantifiers becomes greedy, then `"(.+?)">` will match the first double quote until the last double quote of the line (or of the string with the s modifier)

Answer (score 0):

Using DOM objects is generally better for handling HTML than regexp.

```
$content = '<input style="font-size:12px;width:100%" type="text" value="asd"/>' ;

$dom = new DOMDocument ;
$dom->loadHTML($content);

$node = $dom->getElementsByTagName("input")->item(0);
$node->setAttribute("value", "");
echo $dom->saveHTML() ;
```

This also can explain why: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)